Performance gain after index cleanup in SQL Server
I have a huge production environment - around 1.5 TB database size.
We had monitored index usage for around 6 months and found 20 indexes where seeks are 0. We decided to drop them, but client wants us to quantify the performance gain which we can get from this.
As this is a huge system and found indexes are smaller ones, is there a way to compare performance of system after dropping these indexes? If no queries are using these indexes, then how can this be quantified? Please suggest.

lost in space

We had monitored index usage for around 6 months and found 20 indexes where seeks are 0. We decided to drop them, but client wants us to quantify the performance gain which we can get from this.

Well, okay, how often are they written to? If those numbers are low too, then who cares? This isn't fixing anything.

As this is a huge system and found indexes are smaller ones, is there a way to compare performance of system after dropping these indexes? If no queries are using these indexes, then how can this be quantified? Please suggest.

I'd suggest you do something that would actually improve performance.
If you have a 1.5TB database, getting rid of 20 small indexes isn't going to move the needle for you. If they were large indexes that were written to frequently, there'd be utility in doing this.
Instead, look for duplicative indexes that can be combined and PAGE compressed. Look for queries with high CPU/duration that can be made faster. Look at wait stats to see where your server's bottlenecks actually are. Look at settings and hardware to make sure you're set up to run the workload efficiently. Look for blocking and deadlocking issues.
Absolutely anything other than 20 small indexes.
Put yourself in the position of management: they want you to improve performance, and after 6 months you come back to them with 20 small indexes to get rid of that you can't prove make a difference either way. If I were them, I'd be running out of patience.

It's too late now, but in the future, it'd be good to know what you hope to accomplish by doing a thing. And, importantly, how will you measure it? As it applies here, you could have measured mutation (i.e. insert, update, delete) performance of the underlying tables both before and after the change. Perhaps you have those metrics for other reasons. But if not, the opportunity to collect them in a bespoke way for this effort are gone.
There's also the obvious space savings but since you said they were small I wouldn't consider that to be the bulk of the benefit.

As i have done this in test till now , so there is still scope before i do that in production. can you suggest some ideas on measuring this performance in production ?

Well... that depends on what your hypothesis is. Back to my original assertion - what was your hope in doing this? Examples might be "reduce reads/writes/time while doing DML operations", "reduce data size". The former is probably best measured with extended events while the latter is a simple space used query before and after. Either way though, I would suggest that you revert your test environment so you can test your measurement methodology there.


We had monitored index usage for around 6 months

While 6 months is a good amount of time to monitor for, keep in mind it's always possible there are end of year (fiscal year could vary from calendar year, for example) use cases that may depend on certain indexes too. Such indexes would only be used once a year.

We decided to drop them, but client wants us to quantify the performance gain which we can get from this...If no queries are using these indexes, then how can this be quantified?

No queries may be explicitly using them but every time data is written against the table (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements) they're implicitly used, by needing to be written against as well. This extra write-time is the performance loss you get by having trivial indexes to begin with, and what can be gained back by removing said indexes.

is there a way to compare performance of system after dropping these indexes?

That depends on how complex the overall system is, and how many tables the indexes were removed from.
If I were you, as a shortcut, I would explain the above to the client on how unneeded indexes affect write performance against the table. Then I would demonstrate to the client, an example that shows the total runtime of inserting a non-trivial number of rows (somewhere on the order of 100,000 rows) into a single test table table before and after 20 unneeded indexes are created on it. There should definitely be a measurable difference. Then one could state this demonstrates the accumulation of the performance bottleneck of having so many unnecessary indexes.

Thank you so much , i would try to create some demo for this on my test environment.
